# How can we simulate calls and SMS in Android?

Tags: java, android

Can we simulate calls and SMS in android programmtically? Like in Windows mobile we can simulate calls and SMS.

Comment: @Andreas_D: I would not necessarily assume an evil intention. Maybe he develops an application that has to interact with phone calls and SMS? I think it is just unfortunate wording (better would be *How can we simulate calls and SMS in Android* )

Comment: @Felix - Could it be that he wants to fake *incoming* calls and SMS? Like to have an inexpensive test for some application? That would make sense.

Comment: @Andreas_D: Yes, that is what I meant, sorry :). So it is up to you, @Waseem, to clarify your intention ;)

Comment: ohh.. sorry abt my wording. am working on application, and have no physical device. @Andreas_D, you are right. How can we simulate calls and sms in android??

Comment: @Waseem - I'll delete my initial comment. I was too much fokussed on the buzzword *fake* and didn't realize that 'fake calls' (can) have a totally different meaning. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Andreas_D - It's OK. And just got the answer to my question.

Comment: @Waseem - then please don't miss to accept (and maybe upvote) the answer that solved your problem (click on a checkmark next to one of the answers)

Comment: @Andreas_D - I am new in stackoverflow that why don't know abt things like that. but now understand everything. 2 answer, 1 as my accepted answer and 2nd is useful so upvote for that. And thanks Andreas_D. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you want to test SMS and Call code in android...
so this link will help you to test  [SMS messaging in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) ..overthere everything is explained regarding sms messaging in android...

Hope this answer suits you question...

Comment: Thanks Paresh. This article really help me alot. Now i will start my app coding.

Answer (score 14):

The Eclipse Android SDK allows you to simulate receiving SMS messages and incoming phone calls (as well as fake GPS positions and the like.) [See here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#calling)

I'm pretty sure `adb` can do it too if you're not using Eclipse.